# Performance efficient way of searching for combinations of numbers in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, comparison, combinations

Let's say we have table of all possible guest placements in hotel room.

Here is my table (and the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d01fa9 )

```
CREATE TABLE `Placement` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `people` smallint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `adults` smallint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `children` smallint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `child_1_from` smallint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `child_1_to` smallint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `child_2_from` smallint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `child_2_to` smallint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `child_3_from` smallint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `child_3_to` smallint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `provider_id` smallint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
```

So we want to find exact placement based on user's search. There might be up to 3 children in search query. Every child has some age.

Take a look at this row from `Placement` table:

```
people | adults | children | child_1_from | child_1_to | child_2_from | child_2_to | child_3_from | child_3_to

   4       1          3            12          15             9             11            3            6
```

So, if I want to search for 1 adults, 3 children and children have 10, 13, 5 years, comparing first, second and third child's age range **in given order** seems possible to me.

I can't figure out how to query database when  **order of ages doesn't matter**. So in given example all combinations from these 3 digits: [10, 13, 5], [13, 10, 5] etc. have to return same row from database table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `child_X_from` and `child_X_to` looks like candidates for normalization..Normalization most off the time makes the query eazier.

Comment: @RaymondNijland what do you suggest?